# How to Step Through/Debug Multiple JBoss Projects Simultaneously?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

At present I have a TestNG project that calls a JBoss RESTEasy web service.  I can step through the TestNG project using breakpoints and the debugging perspective like any Eclipse-based project, but I am unsure how to go about stepping through breakpoints in multiple projects.  Does anyone know how to do this?

As a former .NET developer, I am used to debugging ASP.NET and WCF web services and dependent projects by attaching to the appropriate processes running each project (w3wp.exe) in Visual Studio and stepping through each project like that.  However, in JBoss I am not sure if there is an equivalent way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: While the projects are deployed in the same JBoss Server you'reusing (AS, EAP, EPP, SOA, etc...), then the debugger can be attached to any of the projects.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I originally thought, but for some reason the debugger was not connecting to breakpoints set in different projects that were calling each other.  No problem, I found the answer and will post below in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: This may have been just a RESTEasy web service issue specifically in JBoss, not sure.

Comment: Yes, it could. It would be great if you post the JBoss version you're using in your development environment, if its JBoss AS 7.x you should post it in the JBoss forums to get a better answer.

Comment: Ah yes apologies.  I am using JBoss Developer 4.0 and JBoss AS 5.x.  Perhaps you are right for JBoss AS 7.x, will investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some info that solved the problem (running JBoss in Windows).

Edited the following file:

C:\Program Files\jbdevstudio4\jbdevstudio.bat

... by adding this line at the top:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y %JAVA_OPTS%
```

... and then ran JBoss by executing that same batch file (instead of running JBoss from the desktop or shortcuts).  This allowed me to then connect to the RESTEasy project breakpoints from the TestNG project, after running the JBoss AS Server in debug.

Not sure why JBoss would not allow me to connect to the RESTEasy web service as-is.   Any comments welcome.